# JavaFX ChoiceBox selection, on Linux

Tags: javafx

I am having some sort of odd problem with getting the Choicebox to work.  On my Kubuntu 14.04 Linux system, using java version "1.8.0_65", the choicebox does not seem to properly respond to mouse clicks, or touchpad taps.  This has been the case with all of the choicebox sample code that I have tested.  My mouse and touchpad work fine in all other cases, so I do not think that is the problem.  I have tried making a jar file, and running that on my Windows system and that works as expected, so the application code is not the problem.

Also, if I remove the line "choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();", I am able to properly open and select the item -- one time.  It is like some event detection thing is not being reset after the first selection.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Log [a bug report](http://bugreport.java.com).

Comment: Submitted a bug report; (JI-9026128) - ChoiceBox on Kubuntu "locks" after initial selection.